# Asp classic code not working with french accented a character

Tags: html, encoding, asp-classic

I have a html page that submits a form to a asp classic page. The data is being passed as `POST` request. The problem is when I put a character in an input field `à` and then in the asp classic code, when it retrieves it, I print it on the page with `response.write`, and it shows `Ã`. I tried various code snippets with meta tags and `response.charset` stuff, but they all just don't work for me.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: That happens because there're many different ways to encode text in a computer system. It's very likely that the app is using whatever codepage was the default in the author's computer (maybe Windows-1252) but doesn't even care declaring it to the browser.

Comment: So you are saying the computer encoding is overriding the browser page encoding? Is there something I can put in the html or asp classic code that may fix it?

Comment: No, I'm saying that unaware programmers just start typing and don't care with encoding configuration, so the result when coding on Windows is typically ANSI.

Comment: If the page doesn't have an encoding declared explicitly, then it'll likely use the encoding that was set in the editor the code was written in. If that isn't UTF-8, then that's probably why it doesn't understand your character correctly. The author probably just never considered that use case.

Comment: Recommended reading - https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing that french letter with `&agrave;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the html meta tag to UTF-8 rather than any other server side or other html encoding:

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```